# Use dictionary words for new-user usernames

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, display-names

When users first use Stack Exchange, usernames are automatically assigned for them. ([They don't pick one themselves, as that would increase the number of hurdles to jump to use the site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186122)) The usernames [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35839) of the form `user#`, assigned according to user ID number; thus, the user with ID number 314159 is assigned username `user314159`.

This similarity of username is<sup>[1]</sup> confusing to a moderator, who sometimes needs to remember things about users from one day to the next in order to keep track of a pattern of behavior. I propose that, instead of `user314159`, a random word from the English dictionary (vulgarities removed) is used.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Personal experience.

Comment: If all there is to this is keeping track of patterns of behaviour, why not just annotate the account?

Comment: I wonder whether downvoters don't see the need for this feature or think this isn't the solution for that need. If the latter, I recommend you post a better solution as an answer.

Comment: @msh210 It's a big engineering ask for something with very little provable utility. I've never found the `user1234567` format to be a problem.

Comment: @fredley, I wonder if it's a big request. Picking a random word from a standard dictionary? Sounds like one line of code (though I don't know). (Plus the manual labor involved in editing the dictionary to remove vulgarities.)

Comment: How do you make it quicker, and on uniqueness check, than just using the number?

Comment: @msh210 In the longest english dictionaries there are about 100,000 words. But we have more than that number of users, so we'll need to combine them. Now we need to make sure the combinations aren't vulgar (I can think of *many* combinations of mundane words that are very rude). Want to volunteer for the job?

Comment: Are we using a US dictionary? "Fanny" might mean something ho-hum in the US, but it sure doesn't elsewhere

Comment: @random Yes. Words have different meanings within the English-speaking World. This is an impossible task. Places like gfycat work with a much, much smaller corpus of words, and end up having to combine 5-6 as a result. Their solution smacks of a lot of engineering effort. And I'll take user1234567 over CorrectHorseBatteryStaple any day.

Comment: @fredley No need to combine them. There's no problem if two people have the same username, as the chances of two newbies with the same username near in time is slim.

Comment: @random, no biggie. I bet someone's even already compiled a dictionary of non-vulgar non-offensive words good for all locales.

Comment: @msh210 Wat. I thought the whole point was keeping track of users? But now the users' user names are  being reused? *Wat.*

Comment: @fredley, usernames are reused anyway. As long as two people to keep track of don't have the same username (which will happen very seldom), we're okay. It's much easier than keeping track of users with similar names *all the time*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem you're trying to solve is that a mass of "userXYZ" usernames are difficult to distinguish, and moderators view users as individuals that they would like to be able to keep distinct from each other. Assuming I'm correct in that goal...

Dictionary words for user names is not going to happen, although it would be a fun experiment to see how people react to different words.... ;)

However, we are working on a change to our onboarding process that will prompt new signups to set a custom display name. (It won't be *required*, just encouraged.) This won't retroactively fix the existing generic usernames on any site, but we're hopeful that new users will take advantage of the prompt to create an actual persona (display name and avatar) rather than relying on our generic defaults.

I think that solution meets you at least halfway on solving your problem; I'll update here when we roll that out.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think this offers any benefit so I don't think this should be implemented.  The current username pattern (*`user###`*) is much easier than a random word from the dictionary.  Plus, as [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237241/164200) points out, maintaining a dictionary would be incredibly difficult.

Even though they are generic, the current pattern is unique because they are tied to the user id for each person.  I personally think it would be much more complicated to try to tie this to a dictionary and the benefit just isn't there.

I foresee complaints from users because they didn't like the random selected word for their username.

Comment: `+1*100` for your last sentence. First thing I thought of.

Answer (score 11):

The amount of effort required to create and maintain a dictionary of **globally** "safe" words would be prohibitive.

Then you've got the problem (as others have mentioned) that you'll run out of words. What do you do then?

- Allow plurals ('cos that ain't going to be confusing!)
- Allow compound words (your task of getting "safe" names has just increased by an order of magnitude).
- Reuse words (but now you have users going around with the same usernames! Worse than before!)

You've got the Gravitar/identicon - which will be different - to distinguish users.

No, I can't see this one ever working.

Comment: I wanted _cactus_ not _cacti_ !!

Comment: Reusing words is fine: two newbies will have the same name near in time to one another very seldom, so there won't be much to keep track of. That's far better than the current situation, where newbies *always* have similar usernames. Re your first objection (list of safe words), I bet someone's compiled one already for a similar use to this one.

Comment: @bluefeet: SE would have to overcome the pluralization bug, and *someone* will end up getting bludgeoned by a giant S.

Comment: Good shout about the Gravatar - they are exactly tailored to this sort of situation - and they work well.

Comment: Re avatars: duh, of course I should have thought of that. You're right: this is not a useful feature request for those who can see avatars (which excludes me but includes, I guess, the vast majority of mods). +1 on the answer.

Comment: Aside: avatars help (if you can see them), but many of the identicon ones are very similar to each other, such that there are pairs of long-established users that I oft confuse.  Maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 8):

I can imagine that users named, say, "refrigerator" or "cockroach" might object, though I suppose it's one way to encourage people to choose names. :-)

Since the primary issue is moderators keeping track of user314159 as distinct from user314519 etc, would attaching the "annotations" indicator to user cards<sup>1</sup> (for moderators only) address the problem?  That way when you see an answer from that user with a track record of (insert problem behavior), you'll be reminded passively that there's something about this user.  If user314159 has never caused problems you'll see nothing remarkable, and when user314519, that guy with the track record, pops up, you'll see it.

<sup>1</sup> By "user card" I mean that block of gravatar, name, rep, and badges that shows up under posts.  I don't mean the full multi-site cards that people sometimes use.

Comment: Ooh, excellent idea.

Comment: I'm guessing a dev will come along and grumble about database calls at some point. Neat idea though.

Comment: @fredley good point, though this would actually be a place where caching would be just fine.  I think it's reasonable to expect mods to remember that somebody just got annotated ten minutes ago...

Comment: @MonicaCellio No! Caching is not the answer. Caching is never the answer. Caching is the problem. Is caching the problem? Yes. See no c̛achi̸ng̛, hear no cach͞in̷g, spe̴͜ak̨ ̸̧͜n̨̡͢ǫ͢ ̸͟͡càćh̢̛í̸͜n̷͜g̵.

Comment: (Psst -- rep on per-site metas is cached.  So far Cthulhu hasn't invaded the ones I hang out on...)

Comment: While I agree with most of this answer, I am strongly against having an indication of the existence of annotations that is always visible on the user's productions. I want to be able to at least try to evaluate an issue on its own merits, without being unduly influenced by the user's history. Annotations should only visible if I choose to dig further (e.g. clicking through to the user's profile, which does display an indicator for moderator annotations). Having something always visible would also mean a risk of leaks through screenshots. I might be ok with an indicator in a tooltip.

Comment: Good point about leaks through screenshots.  Putting it in a tooltip seems like it would work.